# Move items inside the BOOSTRAP navigation bar

Tags: css, alignment, navbar

I want to move the first item of the list (logo) to the left, to separate it from the rest of the items. I want it to remain responsive and that the distance from the left margin to the logo is always the same as from the right margin to the last item. Any ideas? I share my code.
Please help!

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top">
<div class="nav-item-logo-vista-reducida">
    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html"><img src="static/img/logo.png" class="logo-premoldeados"></a>
</div>

<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><img src="static/img/hamb-menu.png" class="hamb-menu" alt="Menú"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto text-center">
        <li class="nav-item-logo">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html"><img src="static/img/logo.png" class="logo-premoldeados"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-con-hover" href="atermicos.html">Atérmicos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-con-hover" href="pisos-y-revestimientos.html">Pisos & Revestimientos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-con-hover" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Mobiliario Urbano
                </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item nav-link-con-hover" href="bancos.html">Bancos</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item nav-link-con-hover" href="cestos.html">Cestos</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-con-hover" href="nosotros.html">Nosotros</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-con-hover" href="contacto.html">Contacto</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your logo into separate logo-parent div and navigation ul in another nav-parent div then wrap this logo-parent and nav-parent into super-parent div. Then set the padding of the super-parent and set `display: flex; flex-direction: row;` this will align the logo and and nav list side by side and then set `margin-left: auto` of nav-parent div.